# Compute the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, exterior-derivative

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$. We define the Laplace operator by $\Delta = dd^* + d^*d$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $d^* = (-1)^{nk + 1} * d~*: \Omega^k(M) \to \Omega^{n - 1}(M)$ its formal adjoint (with $*$ the Hodge operator). I am trying to compute the Laplace operator on $C^\infty(M)$. I know it should look like
$$\Delta f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|} ~g^{ij}\partial_j f\right),$$
where $|g| = \text{det}(g_{ij})$ and $g^{ij} = (g^{-1})_{ij}$, but I do not get the right answer when I try to do it myself. Here is my attempt:

For $f \in \Omega^0(M) = C^\infty(M),$ we have
$$\Delta f =  d^* d = -*d* df.$$
Therefore, we have
$$df = \sum_j \partial_j f dx^j \quad \Rightarrow \quad *df = \sum_j \partial_jf \sqrt{|g|} ~(-1)^{j-1}dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \widehat{dx^j} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n$$
as the Riemannian volum form is given by
$$\text{vol} = \sqrt{|g|}~dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n.$$
From this we deduce that
\begin{align}
d*df &= \sum_i \partial_i\left(\sum_j \partial_j f \sqrt{|g|}\right)(-1)^{j-1} dx^{i} \wedge dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \widehat{dx^j} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n \\
&=  \sum_j \partial_j\left(\partial_j f \sqrt{|g|}\right) dx^{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\sum_j \partial_j\left(\partial_j f \sqrt{|g|}\right)\text{vol}, 
\end{align}
so that
$$\Delta f = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\sum_j \partial_j\left(\partial_j f \sqrt{|g|}\right).$$
Is it the right way to do that ? Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in the computation of $\ast \, df$: The formula for the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) is $\alpha \wedge \ast \beta = \langle \alpha , \beta \rangle \, \mathrm{vol}$, which also involves the inverse metric.
The relevant consequence is

$$ \ast \, dx^i = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1} \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert} g^{ij} dx^1 \wedge \dotsm \wedge \widehat{dx^j} \wedge \dotsm \wedge dx^n . $$

The apparent sign error is because your expected formula is incorrect.  The Hodge Laplacian as you define it is a nonnegative operator, while your expected operator is nonpositive (check by integrating by parts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still there is something I do not understand: we should have 
$$dx^i \wedge *dx^j = \langle dx^i, dx^j\rangle \text{vol} = g_{ij} \sqrt{|g|} dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n.$$
Therefore,
$$*dx^j = \sum_{i = 1}^n g_{ij} \sqrt{|g|} (-1)^{i-1}dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n.$$
Why do we have $g^{ij}$ and not $g_{ij}$ ?

Comment: The reason for $g^{ij}$ is that $dx^i$ and $dx^j$ are one-forms, not vector fields.  In other words, $g_{ij} := g( \partial_i , \partial_j )$.  The induced metric $g$ on $T^\ast M$ is such that $g( dx^i , dx^j ) = g^{ij}$, where $g^{ij}$ is as you defined it.

Comment: Ah right, thank you very much!